# Constraint Layout - Placing a Viewpager above another view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to place a Viewpager above another view in constraint layout, however the Viewpager extends all the way to the bottom of parent unless I use a set height such as "150dp". How would I make it so that it only extends until it reaches the top of the "Create a new account" Layout?

[image]

Things I have tried:

-Making height of viewpager a set amount of dp (150dp), it works but I prefer to make it match multiple device heights

-Adding constraints Constraint Bottom of Viewpager to top of Create Account Layout, doesn't work

Here is my code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="MyApp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_betterexperience"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appname"/>



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_betterexperience"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".75"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/dividerColor"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_newaccount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Create a new account"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The end result I want it to look like would be like this:

[image]

Comment: In your relative layout where is @+id/textview_signup

Comment: @Vince I forgot to remove that constraint, but it doesn't affect it

Comment: See my answer, add bottom to top constraint and dont forget to set your height also to 0dp so it matches the constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add an id to your Relative layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">
```

**Then in your viewpager add**

```
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/relativeLayout"
```

and set `android:layout_height="0dp"` so it matches the constraints.

Comment: Adding both the android:layout_height="0dp" + app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf worked! Thanks

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES no problem :)

Answer (score 6):

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/unnamed_relativeLayout" 
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" (or set layout_height to 0dp)
```

The preview might be weirded out but will display once inflated with content in app

Comment: Adding both of them worked. Did not in a million years think of using 0 dp for the height. Thanks!

Comment: Of course! For future reference a height or width of 0 maps to "match constraints". Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bottom constraint for view pager . Use below 
app:

layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/relativeLayoutId"

Comment: Then try removing scrollbar also and keep above change.